# Apache .htaccess : serve precompressed @font-face fonts

Tags: apache, .htaccess, fonts, compression

I need Apache to serve precompressed fonts (not using deflate).

My .htaccess in the /path_to/fonts/ folder look like

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /path_to/fonts/
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-Encoding} .*gzip.*


RewriteRule (.*)\.ttf $1.ttf.gz


AddEncoding x-gzip gz

RemoveType application/x-gzip .gz
```

**Response Headers:**

```
Accept-Ranges   bytes
Connection  Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding    **gzip**
Content-Length  **31709**
Content-Type    **text/plain**
Date    Tue, 06 Mar 2012 18:14:51 GMT
Etag    "7200000008e241-7bdd-4ba954a7395a8"
Keep-Alive  timeout=5, max=99
Last-Modified   Tue, 06 Mar 2012 16:11:08 GMT
Server  Apache/2.2.11 (Win32) PHP/5.2.9
Vary    Accept-Encoding
```

The Content Length says 31709, that would be the compressed size, but I'm not able to download it.

Could you give a hint?

Comment: text/plain seems to be the wrong mime type. But why do you want to handle the gzipping yourself? Do you need to conserve CPU usage on your server?

Comment: What mime type would you use instead?
The pre-gzipping is a client requisite.

Comment: Either use `font/ttf` or `application/x-font-ttf`. pre-gzipping seems like a dumb requisite, probably make by people who read somewhere that it would be good for [insert-buzzword-here] :-P. Seeing how much time you have spend trying to figure this thing out. Seems very wasteful. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Oh! I have just realized it was a problem with the compressed files.
It seems to work with text/plain and your font/ttf or application/x-font-ttf.
Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution. It has a bit more polish mostly.

It wont set the type and encoding unless the client supports gzip. Also declares the modules that are used so nothing happens if not all modules are supported.

Folder structure:

```
fonts/  
  Shanti-Regular.ttf.gz  
  Federo-Regular.ttf.gz  
  Shanti-Regular.ttf  
  Federo-Regular.ttf  
  .htaccess
```

Then .htaccess contains:

```
# Rewrite URLs to add gzipped version of font when it exits.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_mime.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  #Serve gzip compressed TTF files if they exist and the client accepts gzip.
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:Accept-encoding} gzip
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.gz -s
  RewriteRule ^(.*)\.ttf $1\.ttf\.gz [QSA]

  # update the response header of compressed file
  # makes browser think mod_gzip did it.
  <FilesMatch "\.ttf\.gz$">
    AddEncoding gzip .gz
    ForceType "application/x-font-ttf"
  </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
</IfModule>
```